# Backbone view listening to model, not firing on change or reset?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone-model

I am using a model to fetch location data from a service using POST.
However I am struggling to get the view to listen to that model when it finally receives a response.

Note I have overriden some model methods to fit the service I am using.

**Model code**

```
        define([
        'underscore',
        'backbone',
    ], function (_, Backbone)
    {
        'use strict';

        //model class declaration
        var LocationsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

            locations: null, //this attribute stores the json response


            //url for http post to get location data
            url: '/testserver/getLocationData',

            /**
                 @name constructor
                 @method initialise
            **/
            initialize: function ()
            {
                console.log("Location Model - Initialize");
                this.fetchLocationData();  
            },

            /**
                @name fetchLocationData
                @method fetchLocationData
                @summary retrieves bulding/location data from service, overriden fetch function to use POST
            **/
            fetchLocationData: function ()
            {
                console.log("Location Model - Fetching Building/Location data from EAS");

                this.fetch({
                    data: JSON.stringify({ "lastRefreshedDateTime": "2015-04-01T08:18:06.000+00:00", "uid": "" }),  //refactor this - string literals which are static currently
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    async : false, //this is bad but it is the only way I can get it to work

 at the moment
                reset: true //tried adding reset parameter but no luck
            });
        },

        /**
           @name parse
           @method parse
           @summary parse is a method inside backbone that can be overridden, in this override we set a model attribute to the JSOn response
       **/
        parse: function (response, xhr)
        {
            console.log("Location Model - Parsing response from EAS");
            this.attributes = { "true": true }; //tried adding an attribute value to trigger "change:true"
            this.locations = response;
            //do other stuff
        },


    });

        return LocationsModel;

    });
```

In the view initialiser I have tried the following binds and listen to on the model however they don't seem to trigger after a response.

**View code**

```
model : new LocationModel(),

        initialize: function ()
    {
        console.log("Filter View - Initialize");
        this.render();
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render); //this only fires at the start when the model is initialised
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this); //same as above
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'reset', this.render); //not fired at all
    },
```

For a collection it was fairly simple to listen to any changes that happened, however it seems to be a different ball game for Backbone models.

TLDR, how can I get the view to listen to a model successfull fetch request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sync` event is the one you want to `listenTo`. It gets fired once a `fetch` has completed successfully. This line in the Backbone source is the culprit: [Backbone source, line 578](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L578).

Your code should now look something like this:

**View code**

```
model : new LocationModel(),

    initialize: function ()
{
    console.log("Filter View - Initialize");
    this.render();
    this.listenTo(this.model, "sync", this.render);
},
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucqga2ud/6/) which shows your code working. I used [httpbin](http://httpbin.org/) to mock the POST request. You can also remove the `async: false` parameter in the fetch request now :) (I've removed it in the fiddle example).